# Symfony2 EntityType field persist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have Entity: `AdWCType` and `AdWallType`. These entities contains static data like directory.

**AdWallType**

```
index  title
-----  -----
1      Brick
2      Plate
```

Entity `Ad` contains columns `wallType` and `wcType`.

**AdType**

```
$builder->add('wallType', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AdBundle:AdWallType',
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('wt')
                        ->where('wt.visible = :visible')
                        ->setParameter('visible', true)
                        ->orderBy('wt.weight', 'ASC')
                        ->setCacheable(true);
                }
            ))
            ->add('wcType', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AdBundle:AdWCType',
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('wc')
                        ->where('wc.visible = :visible')
                        ->setParameter('visible', true)
                        ->orderBy('wc.weight', 'ASC')
                        ->setCacheable(true);
                }
            ))
```

How I can persist `wcType` and `wallType` which I choosed into entity `Ad` on form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Add associations for this fields

```
/**
 * @var ...
 *
 * @ORM\wallType(targetEntity="AdBundle:AdWallType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="wallType", referencedColumnName="index")
 * })
 */
private $wallType;
...
```

and just save the form data object

```
$ad = new Ad();
$form = $this->createForm('%form_class%', $ad);
if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($ad);
        $em->flush($ad);
    }
}
```